# Can you swap online progress from one account to another?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, psn

I had a high rank on my girlfriend's account, but now have my own place and want to take my progress from her account to mine. Is this possible?

Starting back from 0 doesn’t seem right, I had houses, cars and was a CEO. I can log in as her and play on her account, but she doesn’t have PSN anymore and I don’t want to buy it just to play GTA 5, as I already have PSN for myself and all the games I got to play are there.

Is there any way I can transfer her account's progress (my old profile) to my new one, which is rank 9?

Comment: Have you tried asking Rockstar customer support?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to swap online progress from one account to another accou

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem between me an my brother. We have originally shared an account but now we have separate ps4's. He uses the acount I played on (because he needs things his way). The best I can find is the petition to bring back character transfer.